# Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1

Tags: android, android-emulator, dalvik

**here is my error :**

```
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lorg/codehaus/jackson/Base64Variant;
Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1
```

Well, 5 minutes ago it worked. Didn't change anything (*only started the android emulator again*)  - so what's going on now?

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your toolchain is calling `dx` with multiple copies of the Jackson JSON parser. You'll want to make sure your project libraries don't include two copies of Jackson. You can see if an individual jar file contains Jackson with `jar` and `grep`:

```
jar tvf lib/some-library.jar | grep jackson
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error due to an external jar I was importing.  It turned out that the external jar had duplicate entries for every class.  The solution was to re-create the jar file for the external library with *duplicate="preserve"* in the *jar* element in the ant build file (I had access to the full source for the external library).

```
<jar destfile="${buildlib}/external.jar" manifest="${lib}/external.manifest" basedir="${dest}" duplicate="preserve">
```

If you do not have access to the ant build file you can manually un-jar the jar file, remove duplicates and re-jar it again.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem with Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lorg/codehaus/jackson/Base64Variant using Google Drive api's and Google Spreadsheet api's.

Tried all the usual Eclipse fix methods, clean, rebuilding, start/stopping Eclipse, new workspace, etc.

If you are using Eclipse, this is how I solved it without having to manage the .jar's.

1) In Eclipse, right click your project properties

2) Click on Java Compiler

3) Click on Building

4) Click on Configure Workspace Settings

5) Click on Enable project specific settings

6) Click on Output Folder

7) Click 'Rebuild class files modified by others'

Hope this helps.